# Is it possible to pickle itertools.product in python?

Tags: python, pickle, python-itertools, resume

I would like to save the state of *itertools.product()* after my program quits. Is it possible to do this with pickling?  What I am planning to do is to generate permutations and if the process is interrupted (KeyboardInterrupt), I can resume the process the next time I run the program.

```
def trywith(itr):
     try:
         for word in itr:
             time.sleep(1)
             print("".join(word))
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
         f=open("/root/pickle.dat","wb")
         pickle.dump((itr),f)
         f.close()

if os.path.exists("/root/pickle.dat"):
    f=open("/root/pickle.dat","rb")
    itr=pickle.load(f)
    trywith(itr)
else:
    try:
        itr=itertools.product('abcd',repeat=3)
        for word in itr:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("".join(word))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        f=open("/root/pickle.dat","wb")
        pickle.dump((itr),f)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/9864809/3001761

Comment: Nice but I was looking for  a simpler explanation on how to do this since I am still exploring python.

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't just pickle it; there isn't a much simpler solution, I don't think.

Comment: ok, appreciated jonrsharpe..I will see if I can try to understand and examine the inputs at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864809/using-itertools-product-and-want-to-seed-a-value.

Comment: actually,  `product` created out of `range` objects could just be pickled and unpickled with no issues here (Python 3.11)

Comment: @jonrsharpe - as it turns out, your short answer is incorrect. It is pickleable if the iterators are pickleable. I don't know why the OP had not simply trying to run the snippet here.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest thing to do is to save the next group that would be generated. Then a future run can rebuild a new product instance that starts with that group:

```
def restart_product_at(start_group, *pools):
    n = 0                           # Position of the start_group
    for element, pool in zip(start_group, pools):
        n *= len(pool)
        n += pool.index(element)
    p = product(*pools)             # New fresh iterator
    next(islice(p, n, n), None)     # Advance n steps ahead
    return p
```

For example:

```
>>> p = restart_product_at(('c', 'e', 'm'), 'abcd', 'efg', 'hijklm')
>>> next(p)
('c', 'e', 'm')
>>> next(p)
('c', 'f', 'h')
>>> next(p)
('c', 'f', 'i')
```

Comment: Can I ask why you deleted your previous answer? I think it would be better to leave it visible with a disclaimer / link to the deprecation issue rather than delete it altogether

Answer (score 0):

From the "works for me" department:

```
In [31]: a = product("abcd", repeat=3)

In [32]: next(a), next(a)
Out[32]: (('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b'))

In [33]: b = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a))

In [34]: next(b)
Out[34]: ('a', 'a', 'c')

In [35]: next(a)
Out[35]: ('a', 'a', 'c')
```